# Rectangle/Ellipse Program

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I am having trouble with this program that works with Rectangles and Ellipses.

There are 4 Buttons to select, Rectangle/Ellipse/Edge/Label, with Label having a text field
You select either Rectangle/Ellipse to draw and click somewhere in the frame, and it will draw it there. The edge is done by dragging the mouse.

What I don't understand is how to do both rectangles and Ellipses, and the sample abstract class given to be a superclass to "RectangleNode" and etc. Here is the code for the abstract class GraphElement:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

abstract public class GraphElement
{
    private double xPos;
     private double yPos;
     protected String label;

     public GraphElement()
     {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0;
     }

     public GraphElement(double x, double y)
     {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
     }

     public final double getXPos()
     {
        return xPos;
     }

     public final double getYPos()
     {
        return yPos;
     }

     public void moveTo (double xLoc, double yLoc)
     {
        xPos = xLoc;
        yPos = yLoc;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
        String str = "(X,Y) Position: (" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")\n";
        return str;
     }

     abstract void    draw(Graphics2D g2);  
     abstract boolean isSelected(double x, double y);

    boolean applyLabel()
    {
        return true;
    }

public String getLabel()
{
  return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label)
{
  this.label = label;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm totally lost.

GraphDrawViewer:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GraphDrawViewer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 1000;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Graph Draw");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Buttons
        JButton rectangleButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton ellipseButton = new JButton("Ellipse");
        JButton edgeButton = new JButton("Edge");
        JButton labelButton = new JButton("Label");

        //Text Field
        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
        final JTextField labelField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);

        //Add all buttons
        panel.add(rectangleButton);
        panel.add(ellipseButton);
        panel.add(edgeButton);
        panel.add(labelButton);
        panel.add(labelField);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, is it not allowed? If so i'll delete it or something

Comment: Homework is fine.  Just tag it as homework next time.

Comment: Could you post the code for Rectangle and Ellipse and RectangleNode.

Comment: OK, now the matter of it being tagged homework is taken care of (very handy tag that one - has lots of followers) I can move onto another matter.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Oh ok, if i have a homework question i'll tag it next time. And for the Rectangle/Ellipse code I haven't started it yet because i'm really lost. I need some sort of guideline on how to do this, but not the answer outright. I'll post my Viewer class so far

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your question, it seems that you're uncertain how to create a class that has two subclasses which do things that seem "inherently" different.  If you go to the `Java` docs and take a look-see in the `Graphics` class, particularly at the `drawOval`, `drawRectangle`, `fillOval`, and `fillRectangle` methods, you will see that the oval in the name of the method actually creates an ellipsis that **fits in the given rectangle size**.  I think that this suffices as enough of a hint for you to start working on your program.